# Musical Track Database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I'm trying to get the table that's at the bottom of this post, by using SQLite to open the database of which I'm creating. The zip file contains the code which I am trying to modify, and also it includes the itunes library from which I get my values for my tables in SQLite. I'm not sure how to go about adding a genre field in my table, nor do I understand how to extract the last three titles which you can see at the bottom of this page. Any help would be appreciated.

So here's the prompt for my homework assignment:

Musical Track Database

This application will read an iTunes export file in XML and produce a properly normalized database with this structure:

To grade this assignment, the program will run a query like this on your uploaded database and look for the data it expects to see:

```
SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name 
    FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist 
    ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID and Track.album_id = Album.id 
        AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id
    ORDER BY Artist.name LIMIT 3
```

Here's the result that I should get if all has been done correctly:

[Final output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeZ9Y.png)

Here's my code, where I'm having trouble changing the genre portion of the code. I should be getting a genre table in SQLite. Also I need to get the same result as what I have in my table above.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')


fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print 'Dict count:', len(all)
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    print name, artist, album, genre, count, rating, length

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
        ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )

    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the complete code works for your situation:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')


fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print 'Dict count:', len(all)
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')

    if name is None or artist is None or genre is None or album is None: 
        continue

    print name, artist, album, genre, count, rating, length

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name) 
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id) 
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name) 
    VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count) 
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''', 
        ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Your answer is Correct but I really can't understand the Lookup function here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just have to adjust your continue statement to include genre.  I adjusted the code you posted and ran it with Python 2.7 and SQLite and it output a database with no errors.

```
if name is None or artist is None or genre is None or album is None :
    continue
```

I would note that to get the output you show above you need to change your SELECT statement to order by track as well as artist.

```
SELECT Track.title, Artist.name, Album.title, Genre.name 
FROM Track JOIN Genre JOIN Album JOIN Artist 
ON Track.genre_id = Genre.ID and Track.album_id = Album.id 
    AND Album.artist_id = Artist.id
ORDER BY Artist.name, track.title LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, but here's a shot:

Looks like all you need to do is read in the XML file, and put it into a table. Here's how I would handle the genre - I would keep a list of genre already seen, and each time a new genre appears, I would add it to the genre table. Since you are not using foreign keys in the database set-up, you would need to then get the genre ID out of the table again to be used when inserting a song row.

You would do the same thing for albums too.

Comment: Looks like the code should work. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I get a traceback error saying: File "tracks3.py", line 87, in <module>
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: What if the genre table was empty on the first run through? What if you added: `if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None: continue`

Answer (score 0):

the database is modified by adding genre.
just follow basic example and add genre
here is the code using python 3

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3
#connects to database, creates a sqlite file
conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb1.sqlite')
cur  = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;

CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER,
    rating INTEGER,
    count INTEGER
);


CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
)

''')


fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

#create element tree and find the branch
stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print ('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    genre_name = lookup(entry, 'Genre')

    if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre_name is None:
        continue

    print (name, artist,genre_name, album, count, rating, length)

    #insert data into table
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE
    INTO Genre(name)
        VALUES (?)''', (genre_name, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT ID FROM Genre WHERE name = ?', (genre_name, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )''',
        ( name, album_id, genre_id, length, rating, count ) )
conn.commit()
```